# SonarQube - Rule active only for files created after specific date

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Is it possible for a rule in SonarQube to be active only for files which were created after specific date?

I have a rule which checks for particular suffix in classes' name but I want it to work only for classes which were created as an extension to the existing system not for classes present there out of the box.

Is there any known approach to do it? Maybe a plugin for Sonar which allows such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such complex feature, all you need is to use SonarQube the right way, by focusing on fixing the leak !

You'll find more details in the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Fixing+the+Water+Leak), and also in this [blog entry](https://blog.sonarsource.com/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/).

Comment: Thanks, but I do need this feaure. Not only for suffixes but also for couple of more things that I want to check in new code but do not want to check in the legacy code.

Comment: Then sorry, but this feature won't be implemented as it would bring too complex configuration and it will be hardly usable.